# Screen colours shifted

Tags: 14.04, themes, colors, eeepc

I have an Eee with Ubuntu 14.04 installed, and recently I noticed a shifted in the screen colours: the whites are still white and the black are still black, but now light colours are in shades of light blue, and the dark ones are in shades of dark blue (see image below).

I tried to fix the problem changing the theme but it didn't work. Do you think the issue has something to do with the screen connection? Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is this a blue and dark dress ?

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: Once I had similar issue when I was repairing my friend's pc and the issue was in bad connection grip between display and video card but it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have xcalib package installed? (`sudo apt-get install xcalib`)

This package allows to invert the screen colours for better readability of documents etc.

To invert colours (and re-invert) run `xcalib -i -a` from the command line.

If not, I would test it with external screen and check if it is the same (if it's different then you have an hardware issue)